# Comparing semantic segmentation

Tags: computer-vision, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I have 2 satellite images that are segmented using semantic segmentation of the same location but from different sources.
My goal is to compare both of those images for similarity, basically using the components of the images, such as buildings and roads. What is the keyword or method, I am supposed to be looking for?

Comment: Are the two image registered by means the respective pixels correspond to the same object/position within the photographed scene? An example would be helpful.

Comment: no, they are from different sources, and different zoom level... The aerial image is in the satellite image..

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Jaccard index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index):

```
def compute_avg_jaccard(img1, img2, classes):
    classwise_similaririty = []
    for class_ in classes:
        class_jaccard = compute_jaccard(img1, img2, class_)
        classwise_similaririty.append(class_jaccard)
return sum(classwise_similaririty) / len(classwise_similaririty)
```

This will give you a value in [0, 1]. It will give you 1 if both segementations are completly identical and a value of 0 if they are completely different.